# Regular Expressions Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

When using character delimited text, what code allows me to pull out specific segments within a given row? Out of a given set of data (focusing on bold):

1194459945,**11/07/2007** 18:25:45,2,vnta,287.78,2,**7.783**,2,34.111,2,1.3,2,**89.54**,2,1485.31,26.612

Trying to get it like:

11/07/2007  7.783  89.54

Currently, the progress I've made has been: (\w+,)(.+) (
which has given me the first two columns, but I'm stuck as to how to reach 7.783 and segment that out. Without including the entire row. I cannot put \, because that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work.. `^.*?,([^ ,]+)(?:.*?,){5}([^ ,]+)(?:.*?,){6}([^ ,]+).*$`

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of the string / line
- `.*?,` - matches anything up until the first comma
- `([^ ,]+)` - matches anything not a space or comma and stores it in **capture group 1** (your date)
- `(?:.*?,){5}` - non capture group to match the fields and commas for the next 5 fields
- `([^ ,]+)` - matches anything not a space or comma and stores it in **capture group 2** (your 7.783)
- `(?:.*?,){6}` - another non capture group to match the fields and commas for the next 6 fields
- `([^ ,]+)` - matches anything not a space or comma and stores it in **capture group 3** (your 89.54)
- `.*$` - matches anything trailing after this match to the end of string / line

**Notepad++:**

You can use the find and replace tool in Notepad++ to replace the strings with only the capture groups which can be accessed by using a dollar sign followed by the capture group number like so:

```
Find: ^.*?,([^ ,]+)(?:.*?,){5}([^ ,]+)(?:.*?,){6}([^ ,]+).*$
Replace: $1 $2 $3
```

**Test:**

Before:

```
1194459945,11/07/2007 18:25:45,2,vnta,287.78,2,7.783,2,34.111,2,1.3,2,89.54,2,1485.31,26.612
```

After:

```
11/07/2007 7.783 89.54
```

Comment: As you already are using negated character classes, you might also turn the `.*?,` into `[^\r\n,]*` +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good point. That's definitely stronger regex. Notepad++ questions are almost always one-time requests so I'm usually okay offering quick and dirty solutions as long as they work.